# Comparison of functions asymptotically

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, computer-science, asymptotic-complexity

I have 2 functions:

```
 f(n) = n*log(n)
 g(n) = n^(1.1) * log(log(log(n)))
```

I want to know how these functions compare to each other.  From what I understand, f(n) will always grow faster than g(n). In other words: f(n) in ω(g(n))

I am assuming log base 10, but it really does not matter as any base could be used. I tried a number of combinations of n and c, as the following relation seems to hold:

```
 f(n) ≥ c g(n) ≥ 0
```

The one combination that seemed to stick out to me was the following:

```
 c = 0
 n = 10^10
```

In this instance:

```
f(10^10) = (10^10) log(10^10) = (10^10)*(10) = 10^11
c*g(n)   = 0 * (10^10)^(1.1) * log(log(log(10^10))
         = 0 * (10^11) * log(log(10))
         = 0 * (10^11) * log(1)
         = 0 * (10^11) * 0 = 0
```

Hence f(n) will always be greater than g(n) and the relationship will be f(n) is ω(n).

Would my understanding be correct here?

edited: for correction

Comment: Very incorrect and over-complicated. Note that `log(10)` is just a constant (= 1), so `f(n) = Θ(n)`. The factor `n^1.1` itself is already asymptotically larger. So asymptotically `f(n) = o(g(n))`. Your test value `10^10` was too small because the triple nested logs will reduce it very quickly. Using arbitrarily large values does not invalidate the test since that's what "asymptotic behavior" means anyway. But the main point is, this example demonstrates that using test values in asymptotic analysis is bad practice, and can mislead you.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog i input it wrong, it should be n*(log n)

Comment: `n^1.1` is still greater than `n log n`, since (cancelling an `n`) `n^0.1` is greater than `log n`; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial) for why.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog it seems like log(log(log n))) is being ignored here? If so, why?

Comment: It is asymptotically greater than 1, so we only need to compare the other factors.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I don't understand why that's the case. Shouldn't that make it *more* relevant?

Comment: Well it *is* relevant, but since this factor belongs to `g(n)`, and the other factor in `g(n)` (`n^1.1`) is *already* greater than `f(n)` by itself, we can ignore it. `log(log(log(n)))` is obviously asymptotically greater than 1.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog hmm, I guess I just don't understand. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog i think i understand you, the only significant terms would be n^1.1 and log n. setting the functions equal to each other, you would get n^0.1 with the two log terms essentially canceling each other out leading to 1 <= n^0.1. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: At this point I think you are getting very confused. Helium_1s2 's post already explains this quite well - just simple math. I don't think any further explanation would help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the combination sticking out to you doesn't work because it's invalid. A function `f(x)` is said to be `O(g(x))` if and only if there exists a real number `x'` and *positive* real number `c` such that `f(x)≤cg(x)` for all `x≥x'`. You use `c=0`, which is not positive, and so using it to understand asymptotic complexity isn't going to be helpful.

But more importantly, in your example, it's not the case that `f(x)=Ω(g(x))`. In fact, it's actually `f(x)=O(g(x))`. You can see this because `log(n)=O(n^0.1)` ([proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial)), so `nlog(n)=O(n^1.1)`, so `nlog(n)=O(n^1.1 log(log(log(n))))`, and thus `f(x)=O(g(x))`.

Comment: Should be little-o.

Comment: I mean, I was proving big-O (I used the little-ω symbol by accident, and have now fixed it), but you could definitely prove little-o too.

Comment: @Helium_1s2 I guess my question still stands: *why* is log(log(log(n))) being ignored? Does it mean nothing at all or does it? Saying nlog(n)=O(n^1.1) doesn't mean anything to me I guess. If I were to try to prove this, it doesn't seem to be sufficient to say "this can be ignored" here .

Comment: We're not ignoring the term -- it's just that `log(log(log(n)))` is monotonically (always) increasing, so if you have `f(n)` and `g(n)` with `f(n)=O(g(n))`, then you know that `f(n)=O(g(n) * log(log(log(n))))`. If you'd like me to actually prove why multiplying that type of function doesn't effect the inequality, I'm happy to.

Comment: @Helium_1s2 sure thing. To me it just seems to arbitrary to disregard that term and not the other.

Comment: For simplicity's sake (and since we're dealing with algorithms), I'm going to assume that we're only dealing with positive numbers. It still works with negatives, it just becomes more complicated. Let `f`, `g` be functions such that `f(n)=O(g(n))`. Then there exists a real number `N` and positive real number `c` such that `f(n)≤cg(n)` for all `n≥N`. Now consider some monotonically (always) increasing function `h`. If `h(N)≥1`, then for all `n≥N`, `g(n)*h(n)≥g(n)`, so `g(n)=O(g(n)*h(n))`, so `f(n)=O(g(n)*h(n))`.

Comment: If `h(N)<1`, then let `k=h(N)`. Since `h` is monotonically increasing, and `h(N)/k=1`, we know that `h(n)≥1` for all `n≥N`, so also `g(n)*h(n)≥g(n)`. Therefore, `g(n)=O(g(n)*h(n))`, so `f(n)=O(g(n)*h(n))`.

Comment: So in your case, `f=n*log(n)`, `g=n^1.1`, and `h=log(log(log(n)))`. `f(n)=O(g(n))`, and `h` is monotonically increasing, so `n*log(n)=O(n^1.1*log(log(log(n))))`.